# Node.js vs Ajax uploading files on the web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a webserver and now I wanna do uploading files feature. I tried to use Node.js with Ajax but every time when I push button it tells me 'Forbidden, you don't have permission to access /api/photo/ on this server.'. I tried to use everything, but stopped on this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/ajax-file-upload-node-js/
My code is almost same so I do not have to explain it here. Here is my website http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me/node_upload/ 
Do you have any ideas what can it possibly be? P.S. Permissions is set to 0777

Comment: It's look like ROOT_URL of your node app is http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me/node_upload/, but action url of form is http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me/api/photo. Try change it to http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me/node_upload/api/photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that action address in upload form is **/api/photo**

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/photo" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="userPhoto">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
```

But, when you visit http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me/api/photo/ you can see **Forbidden** error. That is because NGINX webserver is responsible for this page. You can see it by looking for headers in server's response (F12 -> network in Chrome).

What you really need is to send file data to NODE.JS express application. As I can see in tutorial, the server is running on port 3000 (from the code):

```
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

So, you need to change action url to http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me:3000/api/photo:

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://ibarakaiev.shpp.me:3000/api/photo" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="userPhoto">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Or even try to change domain name with your servers'ip address and then use something like `http://server_ip:3000/api/photo`